# Can we add a const to an inherited virtual member function

Tags: c++, inheritance, virtual

I am learning inheritance in C++. So for clearing my doubts i am trying out different examples. One such example which i don't understand is given below:

```
struct Base 
{
  virtual void func(int a)
  {
      std::cout<<"base version called"<<std::endl;
  }
};
struct Derived: Base 
{
  void func(int a) const  //note the const here: Is this a new function or this function overrides the old virtual from base
  {
     std::cout<<"derived version called"<<std::endl;
  }
};
```

Note that i have added `const` for the `func` member function inside struct `Derived`. My question is that: **is this member function `func` inside `Derive` a new(separate from `func` inside `Base`) function or does this `func` in `Derived` overrides the old virtual `func` from `Base`?**

PS: My question **is not** about the meaning of `const` here since i know that in this context it means a `const` member function which means that that the object to which `this` pointer points is treated as `const` object. My question is whether `func` inside `Derived` a different function that the one inside `Base`.

Comment: Well, if you execute `Base* p = new Derived; p->func(0);`, what does it print?

Comment: `func` inside `Derived` is a different **nonvirtual** member function from `func` inside `Base`.

Comment: The `override` specifier will make the compiler answer this question. Give it a go.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The member function `func` inside `Derived` is a separate/different **non-virtual** member function from the **virtual** `func` inside `Base`, as explained below.

##### Explanation

You can confirm this:

1. by adding the specifier `override` after `const` of `func` in `Derived` as shown [here](https://onlinegdb.com/xgHJKlvKg) you will see the error saying

```
marked override, but does not override
```

This confirm that the `func` in `Derived` does not override the virtual from `func` from `Base`.

```
struct Derived: Base
{
  void func(int a) const override //added keyword override. This gives error now
  {
     std::cout<<"derived version called"<<std::endl;
  }
};
```

2. moreover, by adding the specifier `final` after the `const` of `func` in `Derived` as shown [here](https://onlinegdb.com/W0mAKtd-2) you will see the error saying

```
marked final, but is not virtual
```

This confirm that the `func` in `Derived` is a **non-virtual** member function.

```
struct Derived: Base
{
  void func(int a) const final //added keyword final. This gives error now
  {
     std::cout<<"derived version called"<<std::endl;
  }
};
```

Combining these two points, we come to the conclusion that `func` inside `Derived` is a **non-virtual** member function that is separate from the `virtual` member function `func` inside `Base`.

We say that `func` that belongs to `Derived` **hides** the virtual `func` in `Base`. So effectively, `Derived` has two functions named `func`. One that it inherits from `Base` which is **implicitly virtual** and second that it defines which is a nonvirtual.

---

Also note that there is another way of confirming that the `func` inside `Derived` is a nonvirtual member function by just declaring it and not defining it as shown [here](https://onlinegdb.com/KJUZChPqd) because we must define a virtual member function. On the other hand if the member function is nonvirtual we can have its declaration without having its definition as long as we do not call that member function.

```
struct Derived: Base
{
  void func(int a) const; //note this is a declaration and not a definition. This works as long as you do not call this function. You cannot do this with a virtual member function
 
};
```

Answer (score 2):

`void func(int a) const` inside `Derived` is a different member function. Once a function is declared *const*, another function is born.